# Поиск значения поля объекта в коллекции и запись в поле другого объекта(Java)

Tags: java, объекты, коллекции

я создал коллекцию объектов ( Clients), в объекте (Client) есть поля "id_client","Client_name"...
затем создаю коллекцию объектов (Accounts) в объекте (Account) есть поля "id_client" "Sum_Account" 
 при создании нового объекта Account  спрашивает имя для какого клиента я создаю счет.Как написать код чтобы искало объект, в коллекции ( Clients), по полю "Client_name" , брало у него "id_client" и этот "id_client"(значение) писало уже в поле нового создаваемого объекта (Account)...

Comment: В текущем виде на ваш вопрос невозможно дать лаконичный ответ. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, какие технологии используете и что хотите видеть в ответе.

Answer (score 2):

Я, конечно, не знаю, как объявлены ваши классы/конструкторы. Но примерно так

```
public Long getClientID(String name, List<Client> clients) {
    if (null != name && null != clients) {
        for (Client client : clients) {
            if (client.Client_name().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                return client.id_client();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Ну и сделать вызов метода там, где вы определяете id_client в классах типа Account